# Hyperlinks do not work when the document is included

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, include

I have a file with the following code

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
<div class="invicta"></div></a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ...
```

and if I open that file, the link works perfectly.
However, in my index.php I have the following code

```
<?php 
  $page = $_GET['page'];
  if (!isset($page)) 
  { 
    include("home.html");      
  } 
  if(file_exists($_GET['page'].".php")){ 
    include $_GET['page'].'.php'; 
  } 
  elseif (isset($page) && !@include("$page")) 
  { 
    include ("error.html"); 
  }
?>
```

So when i go to `index.php?page=<thenameofthefile>` the links do not work, it does not even detects them as link. I am using chrome. Any ideas?

I think it is because the php code is inside a container which floats but I dont see why would affect the links. If you need more information please ask.
Thanks!

EDIT:
You can find the website here so you can view the source code:
[WEBSITE](http://snapi.vv.si/public_html/index.php?page=marcas)
Regarding the comments some of you made regarding security, how could it be improved?
Thanks again!

Comment: Your wide open to [directory traversal attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack)

Comment: It'd help if you state what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: The PHP code is executed entirely server side, so isn't really relevant (although as mentioned, it has major security problems!).
Where it's located with respect to the HTML in your file is what matters, as the important thing for your problem is what the HTML looks like after PHP has spit out the contents of the file.

Give us the 'view source' of the page when you go to `index.php?page=<nameoffile>`. As well as your CSS.
Then we should find your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're including a full HTML file. Do a "View source" in your browser and you'll find `<html>`, `<body>`, etc. **inside** the body of your document. That causes all kinds of messes and there's no telling how each browser will handle it. To make it short: it's wrong.

Second, looking at your example, I think you should read [W3fools page](http://www.w3fools.com/). Take your time and really read it. It's not long and it might save you plenty of grief in the future.

Third, by accessing `http://snapi.vv.si/public_html/index.php?page=/etc/passwd`, I get a message telling me what is your home directory (`/home/u460512479`). After that, I can use `http://snapi.vv.si/public_html/index.php?page=/home/u460512479/<anything>` to get stuff from your **home** (not just web!) directory. Anything readable to your webserver becomes readble to the whole world, as long as they get the filename (which can be guessed, brute forced,...). **Never, EVER, trust user's data**, i.e., whatever you get via `$_GET`, `$_POST`, etc.

The minimum security you need is to strip all directory info from `$page`, for example using [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php). This still leaves your web dir opened, but at least protects the other directories. However, a full control would be better. For example, an array of the pages that can be accessed in such way.

Remember: security must be done properly from the beginning, or you'll find yourself forever patching and messing up your source.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, However I dont fully understand what you mean by "However, a full control would be better. For example, an array of the pages that can be accessed in such way."

Comment: If you make an array with all the names that can be used for `page` and then check the value of `$page` to make sure nothing else was used, you'll have the full control and make sure that no file is included except those you intend to be included.